# Bootstrap items collapsed on page load

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="mainItem" data-toggle="collapse" href="#hardware">Hardware</div>
<div class="hardware" id="hardware" class="collapse">
     <ul class="list-group">
         <li class="list-group-item">Monitor</li>
         <li class="list-group-item">Printers</li>
         <li class="list-group-item">CPU</li>
         <li class="list-group-item">Office setup equipments</li>
         <li class="list-group-item">Motherboards</li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

So I am trying to make the div with class hardware collapsible but i dont want the items to show up as soon as the page loads. I want them to show up once someone clicks on it.
I read similar questions on this topic and all of them ask you to make sure you have the collapse class on the second div instead of collapse show but it does not work for me. Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hardware div has two class attributes and this causes the problem.
Remove this attribute: `class="hardware"`
Or you can remove the second class attribute and merge two values in one attribute like:
class="hardware collapse"